# Is it possible to write VBA-Excel code using php?

Tags: php, vba

I have been wondering whether or not it is possible to write VBA to an excel file using php?  I ask this question for this reason ->  I want to generate an excel report every monday when our users log in.  The reports will pull data from our sql db, and write the data to an excel file.

My question is multi-part.

1) Is it possible to write data to an excel file and save that data without the user seeing it?

If I can, then I know how to have it attached using php mailer.

2) If it has to open as a result of using headers, can i write a vba script to minimize or make active workbook close.  (I'm highly doubtful as it is because I think excel docs open up as csv when writing sql results to them.

Comment: PHPExcel is the leading php-excel project and it does not support VBA currently

Comment: It's perfectly possible to write an Excel file using one of the many PHP libraries written for precisely that purpose, but I'm not aware of any that will allow you to write VBA code in that file as well... but what do you need the VBA for?

Comment: ^^ he should know, he wrote PHPExcel :-)

Comment: Data can be written to an Excel worksheet that's set to VERY_HIDDEN, which will not be visible to users opening that workbook

Comment: @MarkBaker Everytime I've ever written data to an excel workbook, it always opens, as in the file itself becomes visible.  I want to keep excel hidden, so that the data pulled is not directly viewable by the user.

Comment: No matter how hidden the data may be, it will only be protected from noobs.

Comment: I'm not sure how MS Excel can open a file on a user's desktop without being visible. If you don't want a user to see an Excel file, write it somewhere that they don't have access, and then they won't be able to open it.... but I'm getting very confused by what you actually want

Comment: I want to write data from mysql to excel.  I want to be able to save the file remotely once it is done, then have php mailer send the email to a distribution list.  I do NOT want the user to see that process because the process is triggered upon user login.  I have an excel spreadsheet that I have been able to completely hide and make invisible that extends beyond just keeping it minimized.  I wanted to know if I could dynamically create vba code when creating the excel document (almost like a header) that would keep the document invisible.